# ionic one signal plugin cannnot get specific userid and token

Tags: cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic2, onesignal

How to get the specific userid and tocken of the device ?

i got error plugin not installed. but when i push notification in onesignal it will goes to all user.

My app.component.ts

```
constructor(private _notification: OneSignal, platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen,private storage: Storage) {

platform.ready().then(() => {


    this._notification.startInit("a0846c94-146c-4562-af85-6017ae30d490", "test-893d7");
    this._notification.inFocusDisplaying(this._notification.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification);
    this._notification.setSubscription(true);

   //let ids=JSON.stringify(
    this._notification.getIds().then((ids)=>{
      console.log(ids.userId);
      storage.set('ids', JSON.stringify( ids));
      storage.set('pushToken',  ids.pushToken);
    });
    this._notification.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
        // your code after Notification received.
    });
    this._notification.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
        // your code to handle after Notification opened
    });


    this._notification.endInit();
  // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
  // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
  statusBar.styleDefault();
  splashScreen.hide();
});
```

home.ts file

```
  //get the value from storage
  this.storage.get("ids").then((value) => {
    rt=value;
     console.log('Storage value: '+ value);
  })
```

console log is:

```
[19:28:37]  console.log: DB opened: _ionicstorage
[19:28:37]  console.log: Storage value: {"__zone_symbol__state":false,"__zone_symbol__value":"plugin_not_installed"}
```